# ADO.Net Data Services Update

Tags: ado.net, wcf-data-services

I'm finding that my svc I've created to use the latest paging update from the ADO.NET update for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 doesn't seem to work properly and think that it might be that I need to install this update on the server as well as the Build Server.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4b710b89-8576-46cf-a4bf-331a9306d555&displaylang=en

(I've come to this conclusion because as soon as I comment out my paging and switch the InitializeService method to use DataServiceConfiguration instead of IDataServiceConfiguration it works).

When I download and run the update compatible with Windows Server 2008 I get the following message on my server.

> None of the products that are addressed by this software update are installed on this computer. Click Cancel to exit setup.

I'm stucked now as to how to install the update or how to get paging to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a slightly later version of Server 2008 in the end and eventually found the correct download.